# How can I transfer the whole contact to iphone?

Tags: ios

I want to buy upcoming iphone 8. Now I am using samsung galaxy s4. So how can I can transfer my contacts to [iphone 8](http://www.iphone8guides.com/) ?

Comment: I haven't used it, but have you tried [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apple.movetoios)?

Answer (score 0):

Android phone backs up your contact data on Google/Gmail account, On similar hands an iPhone backs up data on it's iCloud server.

Transferring contacts from Android to iPhone this,can be done by transferring data from your Gmail account to iCloud server

Watch this Video for this method -

https://youtu.be/g_5ABwx-yW0

Other method is to use CopyTrans app for iPhone this is shown in the following website

https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://www.copytrans.net/support/how-to-transfer-android-contacts-to-iphone/&grqid=3UysKgyv&hl=en-IN

Best Of Luck.!